DSPy can't retrieve passage with text embeddings in ChromaDB
I am working on a RAG application using DSPy and ChromaDB for pdf files.
At first I fetched the text from the pdf and add it to the Chromadb as chunks. Also added the embeddings of the chunks. And tried to Retrieve the chunk that is related to the query using DSPy. But its getting an error
storing data and embeddings
def store_document_in_chromadb(text):
    chunks = chunk_document(text)
    ids = [f'chunk_{i}' for i in range(len(chunks))]
    embeddings = [get_embedding(chunk).tolist() for chunk in chunks]

    collection.add(ids=ids, documents=chunks, embeddings=embeddings)

And I try to retrieve the relevant chunks like this,
retriever_model = ChromadbRM("contracts_collection", 'db/', k=2)
dspy.settings.configure(lm=llama2_model, rm=retriever_model)

class GenerateAnswer(dspy.Signature): 
    """Answer the question based on the context given."""
    context = dspy.InputField(desc="may contain relevant context")
    question = dspy.InputField()
    answer = dspy.OutputField(desc="often between 5 to 10 words")

class RAG(dspy.Module): 
    def __init__(self, num_passages=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.retrieve = dspy.Retrieve(k=num_passages)
        self.generate_answer = dspy.ChainOfThought(GenerateAnswer)
    
    def forward(self, question):
        context = self.retrieve(question).passages
        prediction = self.generate_answer(context=context, question=question)
        return dspy.Prediction(context=context, answer=prediction.answer)

with dspy.context(lm=llama2_model, rm=retriever_model):
  module = RAG()
  response = module("What is the Total Spend")
  print(response)

When I a running this, getting this error
InvalidDimensionException: Embedding dimension 384 does not match collection dimensionality 768
but when I remove the embedding from the ChromaDB, its retrieving the relevant chunks correctly.
Why is this not getting while using embeddings?

I solved the error with this, but still not retrieving.



from dspy.retrieve.qdrant_rm import QdrantRM
from dsp.modules.sentence_vectorizer import FastEmbedVectorizer

# Vectorizer Setup
vectorizer = FastEmbedVectorizer('BAAI/bge-base-en-v1.5') # 768

# Qdrant Retriever Model Setup
qdrant_retriever_model = QdrantRM(
    COLLECTION_NAME,
    client,
    k=5,  # Increase k to fetch more passages
    vectorizer=vectorizer,
    vector_name='default' # change for your vector name.
)

